# Sublime Text 2 how to change the font size of the file sidebar?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

The current font size of the file sidebar is to small for me. How can I make it larger?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Select `Preferences / Browse Packages…`, and go to `Theme - Default` directory.

Open `Default.sublime-theme` with your editor and search for `sidebar_label` string. You should find something like:

```
{
    "class": "sidebar_label",
    "color": [0, 0, 0],
    "font.bold": false
}
```

You can add here the font size you prefer:

```
{
    "class": "sidebar_label",
    "color": [0, 0, 0],
    "font.bold": false,
    "font.size": 14.0
}
```

Comment: I already solved this by looking at the Soda theme. But thank you for answering, I hope this QA will be useful to other users.

Comment: There is no "Theme - Default" directory for me. In fact there are no theme folders at all in the folder that opens when I do browse packages....

Comment: @Nico probably you are using Sublime Text 3. Package managing has slightly changed. You can find some information [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/packages.html), "Overriding Files From a Zipped Package" paragraph.

Comment: By doing some experiments, I managed to figure out, that there is a small bug (feature?), which causes, that when setting `font.size` attribute to a value higher than `15.0`, entries on sidebar becomes cut off.

Comment: Is there a way to override these settings in a user config file so I don't have to redo it when I update sublime?

Answer (score 20):

Thanks! Some other settings to change font size (in these examples, smaller) of ALL the visible things!

Note that if you have a Project open (a folder) and the tabs and status bar showing, when you hit save you should see the changes realtime.

### Sidebar Tree

```
{
    "class": "sidebar_tree",
    "row_padding": [0, 0],
    "indent": 6,
    "indent_offset": 17,
    ...
{
    "class": "sidebar_label",
    "color": [0, 0, 0],
    "font.bold": false,
    "font.size": 8.0
    ...
```

### Tabs Open Files

```
{
    "class": "tabset_control",
    ...
    "content_margin": [0, 0, 3, 1],
    "tab_overlap": 24,
    "tab_width": 180,
    "tab_min_width": 48,
    "tab_height": 18,
    ...
{
    "class": "tab_label",
    ...
    "font.size": 8.0
    ...
```

### Status Bar

```
{
    "class": "status_bar",
    ...
    "content_margin": [0, 0, 0, 0]
    ...
```

(I couldn't find where to set the font for the Status Bar, this will squish the bottom bar down though)

Answer (score 8):

***Method probably work on the both version of ST***

1. check you current setup theme:

   1.1 open preference/settings user

   1.2 cmd + f and type theme

   1.3 you found your theme (may be not default, may be soda dark;) )
2. install package: "PackageResourceViewer"
3. cmd + shift + p - for open command pallete
4. type packageresourceviewer

   4.1 type theme and select theme

   4.2 select your current theme file (for st3 dark3 theme)

   4.3 cmd +f to find "sidebar entry"

   4.4 type in the block: "font.size": NUMBER to the options

   4.5 save
5. enjoy ;)

Comment: PackageResourceViewer is amazing, thanks a lot for sharing this. For me it was only one option to find theme file.

Answer (score 7):

This question has been answered for Sublime Text 2 but worth mentioning if you are in version 3 is that you can simply copy a package file and place it in your ../Packages/User directory then override the settings there.

**EDIT:**

You may have to dig around some in order to find where ST3 files were placed during installation.

I'm using Ubuntu and ST3's Main Package files are located at opt/sublime_text/packages. I then copy the package to override into the .config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User directory and then make my edits to that package.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which package file?

Comment: Please be more specific with "simply copy a package file"

Comment: @Leonardo Lopez, I've edited my answer to include direction if you're still having a hard time finding the local installation files.

Answer (score 0):

In Sublime Text 3, select **Preferences** >> **Settings - User** from the menubar, then add **dpi_scale** config to the file and save. That's all.

```
{
    ......,
    "dpi_scale": 1.5  //set this value as your need.
}
```

Comment: this changes the font size for the entire application, which is not what OP wanted.