# Sublime Text 2 - How to change the font size of the output panel?

Tags: sublimetext2

When I change the font size in Sublime Text 2 (via shortcuts / config), the font size of text in output panel AKA Build Results is changed too.

It would be convenient to have these font sizes separated. I tried to follow & adapt  [Sublime Text 2 how to change the font size of the file sidebar?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13782271/1136008) and edited `<theme name>.sublime-theme`:

```
{
    "class": "output.exec",
    //"class": "output",
    //"class": "output_exec",
    //"class": "exec",
    //"parents": [{"class": "output"}],
    "font.size": 7.0
},
```

Output panel is named `output.exec`, but it doesn't work. Some other options I tried are commented out.

Probably I just need correct `class` name. I'm unable to find class list which are used in ST2.

Is it possible and if yes - how to change the font size?

**EDIT:**
It's already on wishlist: http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/27388-set-font-size-per-pane/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can, this will however change the font-size for the `console panel` as well, so if that doesn't bother you then simply do this:

First create a file named `Widget.sublime-settings` under the `Packages\User` directory.

Second write the following in that file:

```
{
    "font_size": 7
}
```

Now you're good to go!

Comment: Nice workaround. It affects font size in Find/Replace bars too, but I can live with that with reasonable font size ofc. I will leave this Q open for one week. Thanks

Comment: +1 works great.  I'm surprised this isn't an option in user settings.