# How to set the font of "build result plane" in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

When I am trying to plot a "character picture" by Python, I suddenly found that the font of "build result plane" is not monospaced-font.

I have set "Consolas" as my "font-face" in user settings and can not found any argument to set the "build result plane" font.

I have read [Sublime Text 2 - How to change the font size of the output panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730547/sublime-text-2-how-to-change-the-font-size-of-the-output-panel)

But when I tried the same thing on my PC, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that "build result plane" inherits "Plain text" settings.

I searched my `User` folder and found `Plain text.sublime-settings`.
In this file, I realized that 'font-face' is 'Ubuntu Mono' while my current platform is windows.