# change line height in sublime text default theme after changing the font-size

Tags: height, sublimetext2, settings, line, font-size

I found this link on stackoverflow: [Sublime Text 2 how to change the font size of the file sidebar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781833/sublime-text-2-how-to-change-the-font-size-of-the-file-sidebar)

I followed the directions and changed the font size, but now the font is too big with too small of a line height, so it looks stacked on top of each other and cut off, without any room to breathe.

Is there a json label that I can use to change the line height/padding? Thanks.

Answer (score 145):

Go to **Preferences>Settings-User** and add this two line:

```
{
    "line_padding_bottom": 3,
    "line_padding_top": 3,
}
```

Comment: this sets the padding top and bottom for the code in the file, but does not change the padding of the file sidebar menu.

Answer (score 9):

Go to **Preferences** > **Browse Packages**, then open folder `Theme - Default` and open file `Default.sublime-theme` in your editor. Search for `sidebar_tree` and edit value `row_padding`. It should be something like this:

```
{
    "class": "sidebar_tree",
    "row_padding": [8, 3],  // increase second value e.g. [8, 6]
    "indent": 12,
    // ... more definitions ...
},
```

Comment: This should be the answer. Plus if you're using custom theme and [sidebar_tree] does not exist, simply create it and adjust accordingly.

Comment: Not there anymore??

Answer (score 0):

Echoing [Sazzadur Rahman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31932982/4234110)'s answer about bottom and top line paddings on Sublime Text 3, it works for reducing the line height (as in VS Code) as well by setting line paddings to negative values as follows [from `Preferences` ➜ `Settings`].

```
{
    "line_padding_top": -1,
    "line_padding_bottom": -1,
}
```

*side note: my intuition to reduce the line height is using my favorite monospaced font [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) in Sublime Text.*